# Showing wordpress latest post thumbnails in slider with auto increment

Tags: php, functions, thumbnails, recent-posts

I would like to show latest posts with its thumbnails only in slider. But my first figure element has a class. Can I apply a class to first thumbnail as it is in html structure below? And then Can I auto increment other images, when a user publish a new post with thumbnail?

```
    <div class="diy-slideshow">
            <figure class="show">
<!-- last recent thumbnail -->
                <img src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/snowying.jpg" width="100%" />
            </figure>
          <figure>
<!-- second from the last -->
            <img src="<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
            the_post_thumbnail_url();} ?>" width="100%" />
            </figure>
    <!-- the rest will go on endless -->
    <figure>
    <!-- other latest posts thumbnails -->
    </figure>
          <span class="prev">&laquo;</span>
          <span class="next">&raquo;</span>
        </div>
```

My question is that how can I display other latest post thumbnail in `<figure></figure>`, the above code displays only last latest posts thumbnail, I would like to go on showing thumbnails without limitation.

The structure I was trying to create:

```
<div class="diy-slideshow">
                <figure class="show">
    <!-- last recent thumbnail -->
                </figure>
              <figure>
    <!-- second from the last -->
                </figure>

        <figure>
        <!-- thirth from the last -->
        </figure>
       <figure>
        <!-- fourt, fifth,sixth ... from the last -->
        </figure>
              <span class="prev">&laquo;</span>
              <span class="next">&raquo;</span>
            </div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by developing custom code like following. You can find more information about WP_Query here https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id', 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 );

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <figure <?php if ( $the_query->current_post == 0 && ! is_paged() ){ echo 'class="show"';  } ?> >
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" />
            </figure>
        <?php }
    }

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Comment: This code displays latest posts thumbnails but how can exclude the last resent thumbnail and display it in  `<figure class="show">
<!-- last recent post thumbnail -->
 </figure>`

Comment: I have changed above code to achieve it.

Comment: Maybe I could not explain what I want to do, your codes retrives the thumbnails of latest posts perfectly, In my case there are two figure tags. First one has a class name that is "show". I'm trying to put the thumbnail of last post in it for the first image of slider.

Comment: Actually you don't need to use two separate figure tags if if there is only class difference in it. In my shared code i used only one figure tag but applied show class to first  figure tag of first slider image.

Comment: I asked that question because my slider would't work properly if first figure has not got a class name "show". Then I used this jQuery code: `//Add Class to first element of slider
 $('.diy-slideshow figure').each(function(i) {
    if ( i === 2 ) {
       $(this).addClass('show');
    }
});` it worked, but I could not the class "show" on first figure. But anyway slider worked. Now I'll try again your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WP_Query()` to get all posts. Then loop through these posts and generate intended html.

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()):
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        //html with <figure> to get the_post_thumbnail_url();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Make sure to put necessary arguments and check for syntax errors. Code not tried or tested.